# How to view installed apks on emulator through windows command line?

Tags: android, command-line, emulation, apk

Somewhat straight forward question that I cannot seem to find the answer to. I want to view the installed apks on my android emulator, what is the command to find a list of apks installed on the emulator via the command line in windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

See android [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) documentation. This command directly queries the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Single click drag with the mouse on the screen upwards, then you can see all the applications